# SubSonic PrimaryKey not autoincrement

Tags: subsonic, auto-increment, primary-key

Does current version of SubSonic support PrimaryKey (Int) which is not Autoincrement?
How?

PS: If I don't use SimpleRepository() I can save new record with assigned Id so more or less I can go on, thz.

Comment: Could you please explain a little more what problem you're trying to solve. Is SubSonic failing when you have primary key that you specify the value for?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what you mean, I can tell you this much: SubSonic ActiveRecord does support such keys, you just need to remember to set them manually when creating new records.